# Weird Search Terms Appearing on 1.9.0.1 Installation

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, search, security

Dozens of search terms like those below have appeared on our 1.9.0.1 installation since the very beginning and they're quite heavily used (over 800 times each). I'm just wondering if any of you has experienced the same thing? ... or is it a security attack on our website or a new Google crawl pattern? We deleted them all from Catalog > Search Terms > Select All > Delete but they all came back again today...

Never experienced such thing on any other Magento installation. Please advise and thank you all for your help ;-)

---- TOP 3 SEARCH TERMS ----

```
#1
gqEn AND (SELECT 5188 FROM(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x7174636471,(SELECT (CASE WHEN (5188=5188) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),0x717a726171,F

#2
gqEn%'+AND+(SELECT+5188+FROM(SELECT+COUNT(,",][,('(]),CONCAT(0x7174636471,(SELECT (CASE WHEN (5188=5188) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),0x7

#3
gqEn%' AND 7394=CAST((CHR(113)||CHR(116)||CHR(99)||CHR(100)||CHR(113))||(SELECT (CASE WHEN (7394=7394) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))::text
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt it's a google search pattern, most likely an attack vector attempt or bot like process if the top search results are from actual search requests.

I'd suggest looking through your web server logs for the requests to identify the source - feel free to post a snippet of the logs of you require further assistance locating the source